# JUnit testing blueprint with openJPA in route

Tags: apache-camel, junit4, openjpa, blueprint

I have a test case that loads up the blueprint.xml and persistence.xml at the start of the JUnit but when the test actually runs an error is thrown for not having a persistence provider.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named blacklisting-pu 
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:92)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaEndpoint.createEntityManagerFactory(JpaEndpoint.java:255)
at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaEndpoint.getEntityManagerFactory(JpaEndpoint.java:165)
at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaEndpoint.validate(JpaEndpoint.java:248)
at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaEndpoint.createProducer(JpaEndpoint.java:103)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:405)
```

here is the first part of the log showing the provider is loaded:

```
16  blacklisting-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - Setting the following properties from "file:/workspace/git/jdbc-util/target/test-classes/META-INF/persistence.xml" into configuration: {openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings=buildSchema(SchemaAction='add,deleteTableContents'), openjpa.ConnectionPassword=, openjpa.ConnectionDriverName=org.h2.Driver, javax.persistence.provider=org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl, openjpa.MetaDataFactory=jpa(Types=com.entity.MyEntity), openjpa.Log=DefaultLevel=TRACE, Tool=INFO, PersistenceVersion=1.0, openjpa.ConnectionUserName=, openjpa.ConnectionURL=jdbc:h2:mem:blacklisting;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000, openjpa.Id=blacklisting-pu}
74  blacklisting-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - No cache marshaller found for id org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataCacheMaintenance.
119  blacklisting-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - No cache marshaller found for id org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataCacheMaintenance.
128  blacklisting-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.MetaData - Scanning resource "META-INF/orm.xml" for persistent types.
129  blacklisting-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.MetaData - The persistent unit root url is "null"
129  blacklisting-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.MetaData - parsePersistentTypeNames() found [com.entity.BlacklistingEntity].
129  blacklisting-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.MetaData - Found 1 classes with metadata in 9 milliseconds.
132  blacklisting-pu  TRACE  [main] openjpa.MetaData - Clearing metadata repository"org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository@1766bfd8".
```

I had the test case working using spring and defining the route in a spring camel-context.xml but then I needed to move the route to a blueprint.xml and now it can't seem to find the persistence.xml at runtime for the tests.
I have been using this as my reference along with alot of googleing:
http://camel.apache.org/blueprint-testing.html
Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT:
I have ran the following as part of the setup method in JUnit and the calss is found without issue

```
Object obj = Class.forName("org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl").newInstance();
    if(null==obj){
        Assert.fail("org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl not present on classpath.");
    }else{
        LOG.info("the class {} exists on the calsspath.",obj.getClass().getName());
    }
```

here is the log showing it loaded

```
Creating service instance
Service created: org.apache.aries.blueprint.ext.impl.ExtNamespaceHandler@10a33ce2
Creating listeners
the class org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl exists on the calsspath.
```

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="blacklisting-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>com.entity.BlacklistingEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:h2:mem:blacklisting;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE, Tool=INFO" />
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(SchemaAction='add,deleteTableContents')" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: Have you a persistence provider such as Hibernate or OpenJPA in you classpath?

Comment: Yes, I have openJPA on the class path, and I'm using the openJPA java agent to run the test case.  like I said I have two identical camelContext's one is spring driven and the other is in and OSGI blueprint.  the spring driven version works just fine biut the other one does not.

Comment: And you added `<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>` in `persistence.xml`?

Comment: I amended my post to show my current persistence.xml it has the provider in it.  also the console log shows the properties being loaded from the persistence.xml file.  that was initially attached just below the stack trace above.

Comment: Are you using camel-test-blueprint for unit testing? Its not a full OSGi container so not everything is possible that way. You can use pax-exam for OSGi integration testing instead.

Comment: JPA does not work out of the box with blueprint. Perhaps you need Aries JPA, see https://aries.apache.org/modules/jpaproject.html